# Piecewise homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Is there a name for a Poisson process which is piecewise homogeneous? I.e. time-homogeneous but with a parameter change each increment. Any references appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of events corresponding to a sequence of independent, not necessarily identically distributed, interarrival times is called a generalized renewal sequence or a general renewal process. Thus, the random process you are interested in is *the counting process of a general renewal process*.

Inhomogeneous Poisson processes are different beasts, described by some, nonconstant but deterministic, intensity function $\lambda:t\mapsto\lambda(t)$.

Comment: That's the 50th question of mine you've answered Did, I'll have to send you a cake soon! Is this usually well covered in basic(ish) literature? I'd be happy to accept book suggestions if you have any.

Comment: No reference springs to mind except perhaps some general lecture notes on renewal theory, sorry.